# why does the byte with bits 01110011 not become the character `s`?

Tags: c, byte, ascii, bit

Why does the following program not print an `s` character?:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    unsigned char s = '\0';
    unsigned int bits[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        s ^= bits[i] << i;
    }

    printf("%c\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

So I am basically trying to create the `s` character from a list of bits.
Why do I get some other weird character from this program?

Comment: What does it print?  How about trying to print it in hex so you can see what happened?

Comment: @AndrewHenle it prints this character: "Î"

Comment: î is not ascii so the value are probably not stored well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are inserting the bits in the inverse order from the one they're listed in the source. The second bit will be shifted by 1, not 6 and so on. So the resulting number is

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

which is 0xce, decimal 206 and therefore non-ASCII.

Also, using XOR to do this is very weird, it should just regular bitwise OR (`|`).

Here's a fixed attempt:

```
char s = 0;
const unsigned char bits[] = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 };

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    s |= bits[i] << (7 - i);
}
printf("%c\n", s);
```

This prints `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The binary  number is storing in reverse order in the char variable s that's why you are having this problem.

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

it is becoming

```
1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

in the 's' variable.